# Use an iPad 1 for development and debugging in the latest Xcode (4.5), how?

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad

I still have an iPad 1.  I use the latest version of XCode for app development which will only debug apps on devices that run iOS 6.

Unfortunately, iTunes will not allow you to upgrade an iPad 1 past iOS 5.  Can XCode be configured to debug apps on iOS versions older than version 6?

Another approach would be to upgrade the device to iOS 6 via jailbreaking. I have read that jailbreaking an iPad 1 will give you a path to upgrade it to iOS 6, but I haven't found anything specific to development.

**EDIT**
It turns out that this problem only occurs when I create a new app using XCode.  However if I open sample code from some existing apps (for example [SpeakHere](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SpeakHere/Introduction/Intro.html)), my iPad 1 suddenly appears on the XCode "run list" and I **can** test on the iPad 1!  I suspect that there is something about these apps that is "old" that causes them to work.  Can I simulate that somehow on new apps I build using XCode?

Comment: what version of xcode you on? I am on 4.5.2 and can debug all iOS versions. but yes you are right you can't put iOS6.0 on iPad 1.

Comment: Does the app need to be iOS 6 specific? Perhaps you could make one for iOS 5 and iOS 6, then you could test.

Comment: I don't care about iOS6.  What I'm saying is I can't use the iPad 1 *at all* for *any development* using the latest version of XCode

Comment: Title was seriously misleading (hence maybe the downvotes), have modified to match the intention of the question.

Comment: You can debug iOS 5 in Xcode 4.5, iOS 4 debug is limited to only device on Mountain Lion but can be simulated in Lion. iOS 3 is gone. iPad 1 only supports up to iOS 5.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you're just accepting the default deployment target of 6.0 for new projects.  This means you won't be able to run the application on older versions of iOS, much less debug them.  You need to set the deployment target for your project or target to 4.x.

Comment: I did that and now it's deploying it to the iPad 1 but I'm getting: `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException', reason: 'Could not instantiate class named NSLayoutConstraint'`

Comment: This is a new question, so don't post it as a comment, post it as a new question.

Answer (score 5):

No, you cannot use a first generation iPad for iOS 6 **specific** development.

You **can**, on the other hand, use the latest Xcode and iOS 6 SDK, and still use your iPad 1 for debugging purposes. You naturally can't use iOS 6 features, because the iPad is maxed at iOS 5.

To enable this, you can download 'Device Debugging Support' packages, to allow you to do this. Go to Xcode->Preferences->Downloads->Components, and see if it's available.

[image]

Comment: I don't see Device Debugging Support on that screen

Comment: What happens when you plug your iPad 1 into XCode? Does it appear in the device list in Organizer; what does it say?

Comment: Yes it does appear in Organizer. It has the name of the iPad, capacity, Model: iPad (1st generation), Serial number, etc.

Comment: What does it say below all that? Anything about 'XCode does not support this device'? What is the colour of the status light in the left sidebar for the device? Does your device appear in the run list (see http://i.imgur.com/Blf40.png)?

Comment: Nothing about 'XCode does not support'... Status light is green... it does NOT appear in the run list.  However, see my EDIT above

Comment: Ah, set your deployment target to either iOS 4 or 5 (depending on what you want to support as your baseline). You will need to turn off any iOS 6 specific features for those platforms, or determine them at runtime. Your error above is due to AutoLayout, turn it off like this: http://www.goodbyehelicopter.com/2012/02/arggh-xcode-4-3-auto-layout-is-on-by-default-how-to-turn-off-auto-layout/ Also to check at runtime SDK capabilities for other code, read this: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/developertools/conceptual/cross_development/Introduction/Introduction.html